# pass parameter to date command through pipe

Tags: shell, unix

to pass date and time to the `date -d` command by reading from file

I tried:

```
#cat temp.txt
2013/10/31 10:57:02
#cat temp.txt | xargs date -d
date: the argument `10:57:02' lacks a leading `+';
when using an option to specify date(s), any non-option
argument must be a format string beginning with `+'
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you can use -0 also

```
$ cat temp.txt | xargs -0 date -d
```

> Useful when input items might contain white space, quote  marks,  or 
>   backslashes.

Answer (score 8):

You could say:

```
cat temp.txt | xargs -i date -d {}
```

or avoid [`Useless Use of cat`](http://partmaps.org/era/unix/award.html),

```
date -d "$(<temp.txt)"
```

Comment: if use timestamp, use this command: `cat temp.txt |xargs -i date -d@{}`